# error on line 3 at column 63: Space required after the Public Identifier when parsing HTML to XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

For a chrome project I got thrown into, I have to parse HTML into XML. But I keep getting the error:

> error on line 3 at column 63: Space required after the Public Identifier

The code that throws me this code:

```
var html1 = httpGet(messages);
var html2 = html1.toString();

parser = new DOMParser();

var test = ["<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>"];

xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html2,"text/xml");

console.log(xmlDoc);
```

I tried to find it in Google but I could not find anything that would make me any wiser.

I did find out however that when I use this simple array, instead of html2 in the `parseFromString` it works perfectly fine.

```
var test = ["<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>"];
```

html2 variable contains a full HTML page. I tried to convert it to a string but that didn't seem to help at all.

I only have basic knowledge about Javascript so I'm hoping you guys can make it a bit clearer for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Problem is probably in the text you are downloading via the ```httpGet()```. Try ```console.log(html1)``` and see what's on 3rd line.

Comment: @RadekPech I inspected it, first line is just a <!DOCTYPE HTML.... Second line is <html>. Third is <head> and fourth is <link rel..... So its a basic start of a HTML page.

Comment: *"I have to parse HTML into XML."* Can you explain more about this requirement? What makes this necessary? What is the overall goal?

Comment: @Tomalak I "need" to do this so i can use document.select tag to filter out information that i need to put into an array later on. Im sorry if i dont explain it properly. I dont know much about Javascript just yet so its hard explaining something I dont fully understand.

Comment: @Tomalak Could it be that it is falling over this line: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">` I read this on multiple posts containing my error, but i don't know how to fix this in my situation.

Comment: You can read information from an HTML document into an array just fine, it does not have to be XML for that. I think the "needs to be XML" part is [a red herring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are better off showing a representative example of your input and describing what information you need from it.

Comment: @tomalak Im sorry but could you explain it into words a beginner can understand xD "You are better off showing a representative example of your input and describing what information you need from it" So you are saying i can just use document.select right from the start? I don't need to use the parser?

Comment: If you have a string of HTML, you will need a parser. It just shouldn't be an XML parser, because XML and HTML are incompatible to each other. Use an HTML parser.

Comment: @Tomalak Do you have a link to what i should be using? i have found some links but im not sure if they are compatible with my situation.

Comment: `parser.parseFromString()` is fine. Just don't set it to XML mode. Use `"text/html"` as the type. You will get an HTML document and can query this for whatever information you need.

Comment: @Tomalak After you told me that HTML and XML weren't compatible and glanced over the code again only then i found this exact fix on my own haha(I mean before you posted the exact same thing, wouldn't have found it without you :) )! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Valuable lesson: When asking a question, describe what you want do achieve overall (the purpose). What you did here was describing *how* you thought you must do it while forgetting to say *what* you want to do. Asking questions this way is a typical beginner mistake (so typical that is has a name - the "XY-problem"). Try to avoid it.

Comment: @Tomalak Ill keep it in mind if i need to make another question thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed:

```
htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html1,"text/xml");
```

to:

```
htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html1,"text/html");
```

Thanks to Tomalak, who told me HTML and XML are not compatible so cant be parsed.